# Como executar o script de INSERT com um milhão de linhas no SSMS?

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando executar um script no [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms) com mais de 1 milhão de registros e ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 10738, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 1032
>       O número de expressões de valor de linha na instrução INSERT excede o número máximo permitido de 1000 valores de linha.

Como faço pra executar esse script? Qual o comando SQL? 
**Um trecho do script:**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[cidade] ON;  
GO  

    INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES 
     (1, 'Abacate da Pedreira (Macapá)','AP',1600550,'96'),
     (2, 'Abadia (Jandaíra)','BA',2917904,'75'),
     (3, 'Abadia de Goiás','GO',5200050,'62'),
```

Comment: Você tem acesso à tabela de banco de dados onde estão os dados utilizados para gerar o arquivo texto com o INSERT? Se necessário, você tem como regerar o arquivo texto?

Comment: Tenho apenas o script mostrado no post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [table value constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) possui limite de número máximo de linhas; quando é ultrapassado esse limite, a mensagem de erro 10738 é exibida. No caso em questão, consta a informação “*instrução INSERT excede o número máximo permitido de 1000 valores de linha*”. Ou seja, cada comando com a instrução INSERT pode ter até 1000 linhas; não mais.

Conforme a documentação anteriormente mencionada, para inserir mais linhas do que permite o limite, use um dos seguintes métodos:

1. Crie várias instruções INSERT;
2. Use uma tabela derivada;
3. Importe os dados em massa, usando o utilitário [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162802(v=sql.120).aspx) ou a instrução
   [BULK INSERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188365(v=sql.120).aspx).

---

Para o **método 1** - *Crie várias instruções INSERT*, cada linha a ser incluída deve estar em um único comando com a instrução INSERT. Algo como

```
-- código #1
set nocount on;
set IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[cidade] on;  

INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (1, 'Abacate da Pedreira (Macapá)','AP',1600550,'96');
INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (2, 'Abadia (Jandaíra)','BA',2917904,'75');
INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (3, 'Abadia de Goiás','GO',5200050,'62');
```

Para isso é necessário abrir o arquivo em editor de textos, e substituir

- `),` por `);`
- `(1` por
  `INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (1`
- `(2` por
  `INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (2`
- ...
- `(9` por
  `INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES (9`

O editor de textos faz as substituições rapidamente.

---

Para o **método 2** - *Use uma tabela derivada*, basta substituir o trecho de código

```
INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade,descricao,uf,codigo_ibge,ddd) VALUES
```

por

```
INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd) 
  SELECT id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd
    from (values
```

e acrescentar ao final o trecho de código

```
) as T (id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd);
```

O código final ficará assim:

```
-- código #3
set IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.cidade on; 

INSERT INTO cidade (id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd) 
  SELECT id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd
    from (values 
                 (1, 'Abacate da Pedreira (Macapá)','AP',1600550,'96'),
                 (2, 'Abadia (Jandaíra)','BA',2917904,'75'),
                 (3, 'Abadia de Goiás','GO',5200050,'62'),
                 ...
    ) as T (id_cidade, descricao, uf, codigo_ibge, ddd);
```

Provavelmente é a alteração mais simples a realizar no arquivo que contém o script.

---

Para o **método 3** - *Importe os dados em massa*, e utilizando o BULK INSERT, deve-se transformar o script SQL em um arquivo de dados no formato CSV. Algo como

```
1, Abacate da Pedreira (Macapá),AP,1600550,96
2, Abadia (Jandaíra),BA,2917904,75
3, Abadia de Goiás,GO,5200050,62
```

Para isso é necessário abrir o arquivo em editor de textos e:

- eliminar as 4 primeiras linhas
- substituir `),` por nada; ou seja, eliminar `),`
- substituir `(1` por `1`
- substituir `(2` por `2`
- ...
- substituir `(9` por `9`
- retirar `)` final
- substituir `'` por nada; ou seja, retirar apóstrofos.

O editor de textos faz as substituições rapidamente.

Deve-se ficar atento ao fato de que há localidades em que há elisão, como Santa Bárbara d**'**Oeste. Como no script o delimitador de string é apóstrofo, presumo que no nome das localidades não há uso de elisão. Mas é bom conferir antes.

O comando de importação fica algo como

```
-- código #2 v2
BULK INSERT Cidade
  from 'cidade.csv'
  with (fieldterminator=',');
```

Comment: @Front Acrescentei detalhamento de como implementar os 3 métodos. Sugiro que inicie pelo método 2, pois me pareceu o que terá menos trabalho de edição no arquivo de script.

Answer (score 3):

Crie um (ou vários) arquivo CSV com esses dados utilizando um separador qualquer. A partir daí você pode utilizar o [`BULK INSERT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql).

```
BULK INSERT tbl
  FROM 'C:\path\data.csv'
  WITH (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  -- delimitador
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   -- indicador para próxima linha
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\path\erro.csv',
    TABLOCK)
```

Uma maneira mais simples de gerar o CSV é tendo esses dados no Microsoft Excel e exportar para esse formato.

O seu arquivo deve ter um formato parecido com:

```
1,"Abacate da Pedreira (Macapá)","AP",1600550,"96"
2,"Curitiba","PR",34534534,"41"
```

As linhas são separadas por quebras de linha (`ROWTERMINATOR`) e os campos por vírgula (`FIELDTERMINATOR`). Veja [Comma-separated-values (CSV)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) no Wikipedia.